# THREE JS 3ds Max Gradients not applied

Tags: webgl, three.js, 3dsmax

I exported my 3d model from 3ds Max as json using threejsexporter (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/utils/exporters/max/ThreeJSExporter.ms) and as .obj (which I then converted to json using convert_obj_three.py).
I loaded the models in my page using three.js but none of them retained the gradient that was applied to the model using Gradient Ramp (3ds Max 2009).

How can I recover the gradient so that the model look the same in webpage as in 3ds Max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3ds Max' Gradient Ramp is not supported. You would have to either do it with a bitmap or dynamically creating the bitmap with the canvas API.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. Sorry I am bit new to all this 3d so should I create bitmap in some graphic editor and then apply it using three.js. About the second method can you plz direct me to a sample where its used